# RSA key format is not supported for python

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

pub_key = """
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
mykeyhere
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
"""

public_key_object = RSA.importKey(pub_key)
```

This throws the following error - `RSA key format is not supported`

This is a public PGP key generated with RSA-4096 encryption.  I am curious why this library could be throwing errors. Could there be invalid characters in the key? Doesn't look like there are any , no forward slashes or whatnot.

Comment: Which `Crypto` library is this?

Comment: @AKX https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html

Comment: Well, have you tried `.strip()` on the key data? As it is, it will now contain a leading and trailing newline.

Comment: @AKX Same issue.

Comment: Well, if it helps, you can see the heuristics over here: https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/master/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py#L709 It doesn't look like `PGP PUBLIC KEY`s are explicitly supported; the `key.export_key('PEM')` call linked in the docs you paste generates a `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` key.

Answer (score 1):

For PGP you need a PGP specific library. PGP, at least for the public keys, uses it's own defined format. If you look at your cryptographic library then you will find this nugget:

The following formats are supported for an RSA public key:

- X.509 certificate (binary or PEM format)
- X.509 subjectPublicKeyInfo DER SEQUENCE (binary or PEM encoding)
- PKCS#1 RSAPublicKey DER SEQUENCE (binary or PEM encoding)
- An OpenSSH line (e.g. the content of ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa, ASCII)

So the PGP key format is not supported, only X.509 keys (the certificate contains the subject public key which contains a PKCS#1 public key if RSA is used, like a Matrushka doll) and OpenSSH keys.

---

[Here](https://pypi.org/project/py-pgp/) is the first library that I found: py-pgp, which includes:

```
from pgp import read_key
key = read_key(data)
```

for "transferable" keys, which I presume are public keys.

Comment: Also a PGP public key is not necessarily an RSA key at all.

Answer (score 0):

try [python-gnupg](https://pypi.org/project/python-gnupg/). it takes care of everything for you

[pycryptodome](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/) is a low level library. we are free to pick and choose the type of key and cipher over there but we use it only if we know what we are doing ^_^